# Erased style attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Need ideas how to debug this oddity ...
Inside a complex page full of JavaScript and CSS I have a div tag which has an inline style attribute containing the following value:

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:13px;top:331px;width:685;height:165;background-color:Window;overflow:auto;border:1px solid graytext;">
```

I can see this value both using the network monitor and using view source.

However, when I use the IE11 Dom Explorer I see only only the following style:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid graytext; border-image: none; left: 13px; top: 331px; overflow: auto; position: absolute; background-color: window;">
```

i.e. the height and width style attributes disappeared.
On the right pane displaying the div property, I can see the "width" and "height" styles without checkbox to their left and with Red marking below the value, as if IE11 is telling that something is wrong with them.
I'm quite sure this is not caused by JavaScript, it might be caused by CSS but I have no clear idea what to look for.

Comment: Thanks! of course the damn px again

Answer (score 3):

The CSS `width` and `height` properties require **units**. Just raw numbers are not valid. I'm guessing you wanted to have `px` after both of those values. If you add it, IE will presumably stop stripping them as invalid.

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:13px;top:331px;width:685px;height:165px;background-color:Window;overflow:auto;border:1px solid graytext;">
<!-- px ---------------------------------------------------^------------^                     -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a unit for width and height CSS properties.

Valid code:

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:13px;top:331px;width:685px;height:165px;background-color:Window;overflow:auto;border:1px solid graytext;">
```